# How many 5-digit whole numbers with no 0's are divisible by 6?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

How many 5-digit whole numbers with no 0s are divisible by 6?

I've tried different methods to approach this question but still cannot get to the answer.

Comment: The last digit must be 2,4,6 or 8 and the sum of the digits must be a multiple of 3. Can't you go from there?

Comment: I've thought of that already but it becomes long and convoluted. And also depending on the combination of the first four digits, the number of possibilities of the last digit varies. So i have no idea how to go about that approach without writing out all combinations of the first 4 digits

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, you should include your attempt and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  You should do so in the question itself rather than the comments, where it might be missed.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick the first three digits arbitrarily (from 1-9). That is $9^3$ possible choices.

Suppose the digit sum of those three digits is a multiple of 3. If we pick the fourth digit as $1,4,7$, then the last digit must be 2 or 8. If we pick the fourth digit as $2,5,8$ then the last digit must be 4. If we pick the fourth digit as $3,6,9$ then the last digit must be 6. So 12 choices for the last pair.

Suppose the digit sum of the first three is a multiple of 3 plus 1. If the fourth digit is $1,4,7$, then the last digit must be 4. If the fourth digit is $2,4,8$ then the last digit must be 6. If the fourth digit is $3,6,9$, then the last digit must be $2,8$. Again 12 choices.

Similarly if the digit sum of the first three is a multiple of 3 plus one, we again get 12 choices: fourth digit $1,4,7$ must be followed by 4; $2,5,8$ must be followed by 6; $3,6,9$ must be followed by $2,8$.

So total $12\cdot9^3$.

Comment: Thank you !! That's so smart. I wonder how you thought of that because under exam conditions i would never be able to think of such a way to organised the method in such a relatively straightforward way